# Interpret a matrix as a function

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have a simple matrix that I don't understand how to write as a function.

I have attached a picture of the matrix and have come up with two different answers, A or B.

Can anyone give me a hint on how I should interpret the matrix. Thanks a lot

[Picture of Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcVzj.jpg)

Comment: A. The result is a vector containing two numbers so the result has to be two numbers.

Comment: For your next question, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions instead of posting a picture of your handwritten work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you've written as "A" is the standard one that you'd find in any linear-algebra textbook.

Comment: Thank you so much!!